# Text file not being read correctly in C++ Program

Tags: c++, file, vector, fstream

Here's a program that is supposed to load a little quiz, allow to take the quiz, and then show the results. I've re-written the code and checked for syntax errors feverously but can't seem to figure out why it doesn't load the text file properly. I've also switched between Dev C++ and VS code to see if that would fix things, the only difference is VS code gives me an error code-which varies. I'm using Dev C++ as of this post.

I did have a breakthrough though, I was able to load a text file but the question did not load properly.

the contents of the text file with proper format:

```
1
TF 
5
6 is equal to 3+3
true
```

starting with the number of questions, then type of questions TF= True/false, then point value of the question, then the question and then answer.

This loaded but with no question ( see screenshot below ).

[image: error]

I tried adding more questions and following the format above but returned back to the original problem.

Code

```
/*This program consists of a menu that allows users to load questions to a vector, then display them to the screen. */
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;

class Question // super class
{
private:
    string question, questiontype;
    string answer;
    string options;
    int points;
public:
    virtual string getQuestion() //gets the question
    {
        return question;
    }
    virtual int getValue() //gets the point value of the question
    {
        return points;
    }
    virtual void setQuestion(string answer, int points)
    {
    }
    virtual void getOptions()
    {
    }
    virtual string getAnswer()
    {
        return answer;
    }
};

class TFQuestion : public Question// class for true and false questions
{
private:
    string question, questiontype;
    string answer;
    int points;
public:
    string getQuestion() //gets the question
    {
        return question;
    }
    int getValue() //gets the point value of the question
    {
        return points;
    }
    //function to read lines in a file to create new object
    void setQuestion(string theQuestion, int pointValue)
    {
        string theAnswer;
        question = theQuestion;
        points = pointValue;
        getline(cin, theAnswer);
        answer = theAnswer;
    }
    void getOptions() //prints the options for that question
    {
        cout << "True or False" << endl;
    }
    string getAnswer() //outputs the answer for that question
    {
        return answer;
    }
};

class MCQuestion : public Question //class for multiple choice
{
private:
    int numberOfOptions;
    string question;
    string options[6];
    string answer;
    int points;
public:
    string getQuestion()
    {
        return question;
    }
    int getValue() //gets the point value of the question
    {
        return points;
    }
    //function to read lines in a file to create new object
    void setQuestion(string theQuestion, int pointValue)
    {
        string line;
        getline(cin, line);
        numberOfOptions = stoi(line);
        question = theQuestion;
        points = pointValue;
        //get the individual choice lines and load to options array
        for (int count = 0; count < numberOfOptions; count++) {
            getline(cin, line);
            options[count] = line;
        }
        //get the answer from the file
        getline(cin, line);
        answer = line;
    }
    void getOptions() // gets the options
    {
        char first = 'A';
        for (int count = 0; count < numberOfOptions; count++)
        {
            cout << first++ << ". " << options[count] << "\n";
        }
    }
    string getAnswer()// prints the answer
    {
        return answer;
    }
};

class Exam //class for exams
{
private:
    vector <Question*> myQuestions; //creates new vector to hold Question objects
    int numquestions;
public:
    int loadExam(ifstream& fin) //function to read file contents and store objects in the vector
    {
        myQuestions.clear();
        string line, theQuestion, questiontype, theAnswer;
        int questionvalue;
        streambuf* cinbuf = cin.rdbuf(); //save old buf
        cin.rdbuf(fin.rdbuf()); //redirect std::cin to file
        //get the number of questions from the first line in the file
        getline(cin, line);
        numquestions = stoi(line);
        for (int count = 0; count < numquestions; count++)
        {
            getline(cin, line);
            questiontype = line;
            getline(cin, line);
            questionvalue = stoi(line);

            if (questiontype == "TF")
            {
                myQuestions.push_back(new TFQuestion); //add new TFQuestion to the vector
                getline(cin, theQuestion);
                myQuestions[count]->setQuestion(theQuestion, questionvalue);
            }

            if (questiontype == "MC")
            {
                myQuestions.push_back(new MCQuestion); //add new MC question to the vector
                getline(cin, theQuestion);
                myQuestions[count]->setQuestion(theQuestion, questionvalue);
            }
        }
        cin.rdbuf(cinbuf); //restore cin to standard input

        return myQuestions.size(); //returns vector size to validate data properly added.
    }

    //function to display each question for the user
    void displayExamQuestion(int i)
    {
        cout << "Question # " << (i + 1) << endl;
        cout << myQuestions[i]->getQuestion() << endl;
        myQuestions[i]->getOptions();
    }
    int getNumberOfQuestions()
    {
        return myQuestions.size();
    }
    string getCorrectAnswer(int i)
    {
        return myQuestions[i]->getAnswer();
    }
    int getPointsValue(int i)
    {
        return myQuestions[i]->getValue();
    }
};

class Student
{
private:
    int pointsPossible;
    int pointsEarned;
public:
    Student()
    {
        pointsPossible = 0;
        pointsEarned = 0;
    }
    int getPointsPossible()
    {
        return pointsPossible;
    }
    int getPointsEarned()
    {
        return pointsEarned;
    }
    void setPointsPossible(int points)
    {
        pointsPossible = points;
    }
    void setPointsEarned(int points)
    {
        pointsEarned = points;
    }
};

//Function prototypes
string ConvertToupper(string);
int displayMenu();

int main()
{
    Exam myExam;
    Student s;
    /*initialize numquestions variable to zero helps with data validation. Number should change
    if loadExam function is successful.*/
    int numquestions = 0;
    int choice;
    try
    {   //loop to be executed until user chooses option 4 to quit the program
        while ((choice = displayMenu()) != 4)
            switch (choice)
            {
            case 1: //execute when load exam is chosen
            {
                string file;
                cout << "Enter the name of the file you would like to load questions from: ";
                cin >> file;
                ifstream fin;
                fin.open(file.c_str());
                while (!fin)
                {
                    cout << "Error.  File not found. Try again." << endl;
                    cout << "Enter the name of the file including the extension (i.e. 'test.txt'): " << endl;
                    cin >> file;
                    fin.open(file.c_str());
                }
                numquestions = myExam.loadExam(fin);
                cout << "Success! Number of questions loaded:  " << numquestions << endl; //inform user of number of questions loaded
                fin.close();
                system("PAUSE");
            }
            break;
            case 2: //execute when display exam is chosen.
                if (numquestions == 0) //this would indicate no questions are loaded
                {
                    cout << "No questions to display. Questions might not have been loaded." << endl;
                    system("PAUSE");
                }
                else //executes as long as there are questions loaded in the vector
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < myExam.getNumberOfQuestions(); i++)
                    {
                        system("CLS"); //clear the screen for each new question
                        int pts = myExam.getPointsValue(i); //variable to be used for points possible and earned
                        s.setPointsPossible(s.getPointsPossible() + pts); //add to the total possible points
                        myExam.displayExamQuestion(i);
                        cout << endl << "Please enter your answer :  ";
                        string answer;
                        cin >> answer;
                        //convert user input and correct answer to ensure proper capitalization
                        answer = ConvertToupper(answer);
                        string corrAnswer = ConvertToupper(myExam.getCorrectAnswer(i));
                        cout << "Correct answer is: " << corrAnswer << endl;
                        if (answer == corrAnswer) //output if user answers correctly
                        {
                            cout << "Correct! Good job!" << endl;
                            s.setPointsEarned(s.getPointsEarned() + pts); //add points value to points earned
                        }
                        else //output if user answers incorrectly
                        {
                            cout << "That is incorrect." << endl;
                        }
                        system("PAUSE");
                    }
                    cout << endl << "You have completed the exam!" << endl; //informs user they have reached end of exam
                    system("PAUSE");
                }
                break;
            case 3: //displays user exam results
            {
                try
                {   //obtain and convert points earned and points possible to double and calculate percentage
                    double totalScore = ((double)s.getPointsEarned() / (double)s.getPointsPossible()) * 100.0;
                    if ((s.getPointsPossible() == 0) && (s.getPointsEarned() == 0))
                    {
                        cout << "No results to display. You need to take an exam first." << endl;
                        system("PAUSE");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cout << "Total points possible: " << s.getPointsPossible() << endl;
                        cout << "Total points earned:  " << s.getPointsEarned() << endl;
                        cout << "Final Score: " << fixed << setprecision(0) << totalScore << "% " << endl;
                        system("PAUSE");
                    }
                }
                catch (runtime_error& e) //in the event of a divide by zero exception occurs
                {
                    cout << "An exception occurred: " << e.what() << endl;
                }  
                break;
            }
            default: cout << "Invalid choice.  Try again.\n";
            }
    }
    catch (...) //if any exception occurs while running the program
    {
        cout << "Your choice caused an issue. Check your code. " << endl;
    }
    cout << "Thank you!" << endl;
    getchar();
    return 0;
}

string ConvertToupper(string s) //converts only the first character of a string to uppercase
{
    string str = s;
    str[0] = toupper(str[0]);
    return str;
}

int displayMenu() //menu function
{
    int choice;
    system("CLS"); //clears the screen to make it easier to read for users
    cout << "Enter your choice for this Exam." << endl;
    cout << "1.   Load Exam " << endl;
    cout << "2.   Take Exam " << endl;
    cout << "3.   Display Exam Results " << endl;
    cout << "4.   Quit" << endl;
    cin >> choice;
    return choice;
}
```

Comment: image error https://imgur.com/B2GovuR

Comment: Operations with `rdbuf` seem strange, does `getline(fin, line);` work?

Comment: Did you try to debug your program step-by-step?

Comment: This is not quite a [mcve]. Maybe, write a separate test program first to read only the file. Once, it works as expected you may apply the learnt lessons to your application. If not, you have a [mcve] to expose here.

Comment: Why do the child classes of `Question` duplicate the variables of the `Question` base class?  You may want to consider making the members as `protected` rather than private.

Comment: Hello everyone, I figured it out , there spaces behind each line in the text file. Once I removed the spaces the program loaded.

Comment: If you intend to leave this question "for eternity", please, write a [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Otherwise, you may consider to delete your question. Remarking questions as "answered" or "solved" in title is not usual in SO. (Answered questions are remarked as such in the overview in general.)

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in the text file. The cursor has to fall on the last character of each line. If the cursor does not fall, on the last character of every line when loading the file. The program will either not load the file or present a runtime error.

I'm not sure why this causes an error from a technical point of view.